# Why is this question getting flagged ''too broad''?

Tags: discussion

A question to the moderators and top users :

I made a [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53664/identification-of-sunbirds) on identification of sunbirds that was downvoted twice and had been flagged as too broad.

I would like to know what aspects of the question make it too broad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps someone may have thought that you are asking about many birds. One week has gone since you asked the question and the question is not closed. So the community consensus is that the question is not to be closed.

You can't really stop people from casting down/close votes but the community, overall, is apparently not being very hostile and biased.

Comment: I was mostly concerned about the flagging. As I had copied the sentence from chat, the down vote part was there as well.